# Move files shell program

Tags: shell, programming, system-programming

Hello i have got problem, on shell program(.sh), with this code  I should copy the file JPG from the directory sorgente to destinazione 
but the code does not work, can you help me!!

```
#!/bin/bash

sorgente=$1
destinazione=$2


cd sorgente

for i in *.jpg
do

  #controllo che la directory sia leggibile
   if test -r $i 
   then

     #controllo che il file $i non sia presente nella destinazione
       if test -r $2 
         then 
            #in questo caso è presente nella destinazione
          mv $i "$destinazione/duplicati"  

         else
            mv $i "$destinazione"
       fi

  else
       echo "il file $i non è leggibile da questo utente"

   fi

done
```

Comment: What is the error you're getting or what about it is "not working".  Also, why are you testing if you have read privs on the destination directory, they shouldn't matter for anything you're doing to it.  Also, you should quote your variables to prevent word splitting, and finally you're doing `cd sorgente` without `$` and you probably want `cd "$sorgente"`

Comment: `test -r $2` tests if the directory is readable, that's not the same as testing if it already contains a file named `$i`.

Comment: All other things aside, GNU `mv` has a `--backup` switch that can generate a `foo.jpg.1` in the target directory if `foo.jpg` already exists there.

Answer (score 0):

I have solve with this code:

```
sorgente=$1
destinazione=$2

echo "\n Sorgente:  $sorgente \n" 
echo "\n Destinazione:  $destinazione \n"


cd "$sorgente"

for i in *.JPG
do

  #controllo che la directory sia leggibile
   if test -r "$i" 
   then

     #controllo che il file $i non sia presente nella destinazione
       if test -r "$2" 
         then 
            #in questo caso è presente nella destinazione
            # mv "$i" "$destinazione/duplicati"  

           # else
            mv "$i" "$destinazione"
       fi

  else
       echo "il file $i non è leggibile da questo utente"

   fi

done
```